# How can you call a Laravel Blade directive inside of another directive?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using the Wordpress framework Sage and it comes bundled with Blade templating. Sage has a custom directive called `@asset` which returns an asset URL. For example `@assets('images/my-image.jpg')`.

I want to use that directive inside of an `@include`. Is it possible?

Example, I'd expect this to work but it returns an error saying that `@asset` is an undefined function, but it works fine outside of the `@include`:

```
@include('partials/components/hero', ['data' => [
    'heading' => 'Hero heading example from pattern library',
    'subtitle_1' => 'Hero subtitle example from pattern library',
    'subtitle_2' => 'Hero subtitle example from pattern library',
    'show_illustration' => true,
    'illustration_src' =>  @asset('images/illustrations/1.
]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot.
You can however just send the path string to your partial and use the `@asset` directive in your partial.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-asset) helper function instead or pass the string directly to the path of your asset.

**Note:** Based on the code you have shown (`@asset('images/illustrations/1.`) that is incorrect syntax. It is missing the closing quote and bracket.